# Plot a contour of multivariate normal PDF of a given MVN in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, contour, gaussian, normal-distribution

I have a bivariate gaussian I defined as follow:

```
I=[1 0;0 1];
mu=[0,0];
sigma=0.5*I;
beta = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,100);  %100x2 matrix where each column vector is a variable.
```

now I want to plot a contour of the pdf of the above matrix. What I did:

```
Z = mvnpdf(beta,mu,sigma);  %100x1 pdf matrix
```

Now I want to plot a contour of the bivariate gaussian beta.  I know I should use the command contour but this one require Z to be a square matrix.  how do I solve this? I am very confused and not sure how to plot the contour of the bivariate gaussian!! ANY HELP IS GREATLY APPRECIATED..

Thank you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to define your `x`, `y` axes and use `meshgrid` (or `ndgrid`) to generate all combinations of x, y values, in the form of two matrices `X` and `Y`. You then compute the `Z` values (your Gaussian pdf) for those `X` and `Y`, and plot `Z` as a function of `X` , `Y` using `contour` (contour plot), or perhaps `surf` (3D plot).

```
mu = [0,0]; %// data
sigma = [.5 0; 0 .5]; %// data
x = -5:.1:5; %// x axis
y = -4:.1:4; %// y axis

[X Y] = meshgrid(x,y); %// all combinations of x, y
Z = mvnpdf([X(:) Y(:)],mu,sigma); %// compute Gaussian pdf
Z = reshape(Z,size(X)); %// put into same size as X, Y
%// contour(X,Y,Z), axis equal  %// contour plot; set same scale for x and y...
surf(X,Y,Z) %// ... or 3D plot
```

[image: Graph obtained with <code>contour(X,Y,Z), axis equal</code>]
[image: Graph obtained with <code>surf(X,Y,Z)</code>]

Comment: This code works also perfectly in Octave, provided that the statistics package is loaded `pkg load statistics` :)