# Projecting multivariate distribution to 2d plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to do the same thing as the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170083/plot-a-contour-of-multivariate-normal-pdf-of-a-given-mvn-in-matlab) question did, but not in MATLAB, but in Python with matplotlib. So far I've completed the 3D plot with the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

mu_x = 0
mu_y = 0

x = np.linspace(-10,10,500)
y = np.linspace(-10,10,500)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
pos = np.empty(X.shape + (2,))
pos[:, :, 0] = X; pos[:, :, 1] = Y
rv = multivariate_normal([mu_x, mu_y], [[1, 0.8], [0.8, 1]])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, rv.pdf(pos),cmap='viridis',linewidth=0)
ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')
ax.auto_scale_xyz([-10, 10], [-10, 10], [0, 0.5])
plt.show()
```

But how can I project this to a 2D contour plot? I'm trying

```
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, rv)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
```

but apparently this isn't right, since Z is not an array type (I get the error `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number` for the line `CS = plt.contour(X, Y, rv)`). How can I project the multivariate distribution to a 2D contour plot? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply the same array to `contour` as you supply to `plot_surface`.

```
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, rv.pdf(pos))
```